# How to return total number of exact matches in a query?

Tags: mysql

I am performing a query of items on order. When outputting the results, instead of listing the same exact item more than once, I would rather show the total number of entries for that exact item. For example, my table is setup like:

```
ID    Item    Color    Size
1     506     8        3
2     523     2        1
3     506     8        3
4     511     8        2
```

As items are sold, they are added to this table of items on order. So, when performing this query, I would like to return an array like:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Qty] => 2
        [Item] => 506
        [Color] => 8
        [Size] => 3
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Qty] => 1
        [Item] => 523
        [Color] => 2
        [Size] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Qty] => 1
        [Item] => 511
        [Color] => 8
        [Size] => 2
    )
)
```

Comment: missing the query you're already using to edit it accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to group by the columns that define the "exact match" : in your case "Item", "Color" and "Size"

Try something like this :

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) as Qty,
    Item,
    Color,
    Size
FROM [YOUR_TABLE_NAME]
GROUP BY Item, Color, Size
```